# Hooking input filed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field called "box" that is defined as:

```
<input type="text" id="box" name="box" value="Hahaha" required>
```

I want to add a hook(Usign getter/setter) that in each accessing of the content of the field, I will change it without changing the original content seen in box.

This means that the user sees X, but when he reads the content he gets X after a change.
What I tried:

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function createGetSetValue( inputElement ){
    var value = inputElement.value;
    Object.defineProperty( inputElement, "value", {
        get: function(){return value;},
        set: function( v ){value = v + '1';}
    });
    return inputElement;
};

createGetSetValue( box );
console.log( box.value )
```

But when the content changes through the UI it does not work.
What to do?

Comment: what about using the input [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)? did you try it?

Comment: @Roy.B     inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        value = this.value;
    });
Chnage also the UI content

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic setup for handling input onchange:

```
<input type="text" id="box" name="box" value="Hahaha" onchange="setValue(this.value)" required>
```

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function setValue(value) {
  box.value = value + '1';
}
function getValue() {
  return box.value;
}
```

Building on top of this, you could add variables to store the value separately and show the user something different, or store different input. The way this example works - to see the change happen, you need to move the focus away from the text input (i.e. click somewhere else on the page). If you prefer to have the input change on every keystroke, you could look into `onkeydown` events.